# How to use convolution NN to model time series data

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, lstm

I have a 2d matrix with rows representing the different price levels and columns representing the last N bars.
For example, the 2d matrix looks like:

```
Price   Bar0   Bar1   Bar2   Bar3   Bar4   Bar5  ...
0         0     0      1      1       0     0
1         1     0      1      1       0     1
2         1     1      1      1       1     1
3         1     1      0      1       1     0
4         0     0      0      0       1     0
...
```

this matrix will represent, price data of:

```
       High    Low
Bar0    3       1
Bar1    3       2
Bar2    2       0
Bar3    3       0
Bar4    4       2
Bar5    2       1
```

I would like to do feature extraction using convolution NN before passing to LSTM for supervised learning.  There should be other indicators like moving averages, also passed along to LSTM for learning.

```
# LSTM and CNN for sequence classification in the IMDB dataset

import numpy
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D

from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D

from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset but only keep the top n words, zero the rest
top_words = 5000
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)
# truncate and pad input sequences
max_review_length = 500
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)
# create the model
embedding_vecor_length = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length,    input_length=max_review_length))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I have read somewhere on the above piece of codes for sequence classification, I am trying to adapt for time-series.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a wonderful package that search for best architecture for time series modelling:
GitHub.com/NLeSC/mcfly

It provides DeepConvLSTM model that suits my purpose.